# CSS HR Fade wont work on IE/FF, works on Chrome

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

My site: http://travisingram.net/

My code:

```
<div style="font-family: Comic Sans MS;text-align: left;font-size: 22px;">Welcome to My Blog!</div>
<hr style="
    border: 0px;
    height: 1.3px;
    background: black;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(linear, 0 0, 150% 0, from(#FFD700), to(#1F1F1F), color-stop(100%, black));
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 150% 0, from(#FFD700), to(#1F1F1F), color-stop(100%, black));
    background:  linear-gradient(linear, 0 0, 150% 0, from(#FFD700), to(#1F1F1F), color-stop(100%, black));" />
```

If you visit the homepage and look at the sidebar, you see the HR line, in Chrome it works just fine, Yellow to Black. But in FF and IE, the color is just Black. Is my code incorrect or something?

Comment: Your real problem here is that the `-webkit-gradient` syntax is nothing like the standard `linear-gradient` syntax....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CIHds

This is a cross browser gradient that works in IE and Mozilla.